# Conflicts between JavaFX and Socket

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, javafx

I'm trying to set up a Server with a simple GUI where I print when a client make a connection and for its standard operations. The problem happens when I try to execute it, because the GUI doesn't start (even if NetBeans says that the program is executed) and I can't understand if there is a sort of conflict between the threads or if I called it in a wing way. This is the code where the program starts:

```
public class Server extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    FXMLLoader sLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("server.fxml"));

    BorderPane root = new BorderPane(sLoader.load());

    ServerController sController = sLoader.getController();
    sController.initModel();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

This is the controller of the Server, I put here, in the init function, the part where the Socket waits for the client:

```
public class ServerController {

@FXML
private TextArea textarea;

public void initModel() {
    try {
        int i = 1;
        ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(5000);

        while (true) {
            Socket incoming = s.accept(); // si mette in attesa di richiesta di connessione e la apre
            textarea.setText("In attesa di connessioni...");
            Runnable r = new ThreadedEchoHandler(incoming, i);
            new Thread(r).start();
            i++;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

class ThreadedEchoHandler implements Runnable {

    private Socket incoming;
    private int counter;

    /**
     * Constructs a handler.
     *
     * @param i the incoming socket
     * @param c the counter for the handlers (used in prompts)
     */
    public ThreadedEchoHandler(Socket in, int c) {
        incoming = in;
        counter = c;
    }

    //Con questo gestisco le stringhe
    public void run() {
        try {
            try {
                InputStream inStream = incoming.getInputStream();
                OutputStream outStream = incoming.getOutputStream();

                Scanner in = new Scanner(inStream);
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outStream, true);

                //out.println("Hello! Enter BYE to exit.");

                // echo client input
                boolean done = false;
                while (!done && in.hasNextLine()) {
                    String line = in.nextLine();
                    //out.println("Echo: " + line);
                    //System.out.println("ECHO: " + line);
                    if (line.trim().equals("BYE")) {
                        done = true;
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                incoming.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're doing an infinite loop with this statement `while (true) {...}`. And you're doing it in the JavaFX thread.

Comment: So how do I can manage thread with JavaFX? Because I need to loop to wait for 1 or more clients, right?

Comment: I do not know what is your needs and your architectural choices. Moreover I am not sure about what you called `client`. But in this case, I always begin by the simplest way : make it work with one client for the first step. Once it will work, think about the multiplicity of client and have a look on how multithread works in JavaFX.